# Scientific realism vs. theory change: Would a causal theory of reference make referential continuity trivial?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, scientific-realism

Scientific realists sometimes resort to a [causal-historical theory of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_theory_of_reference) in order to reconcile realism with theory change roughly as follows. If the reference of some expression is *not* determined simply by way of describing it, but through a reference-fixing naming and a reference-preserving chain of communication, then successor theories can often be seen as correcting *past misconceptions about the same entities*.

Now, my question is not about general pros and cons. There is among other things the worry that such a move might backfire, for referential continuity threatens to become trivial on this account:

> “If the unobservable causal agent behind a set of phenomena is given
> only existentially, and if no description
> of its nature is essentially employed in fixing the reference of the
> terms that purport to refer to it, then the term will never fail to
> refer to something: to whatever causes the relevant phenomena […].
> Hence, there can be no referential failure […].” (Psillos 1999, Scientific realism, p. 290)

Isn't there something wrong with this objection? I sort of fail to pin it down and haven't come across much relevant literature, but maybe you know of something?

Comment: ... 'the term will refer to something', is an unsupported stipulation, without any demonstration.

Comment: This is an attractive idea, often pursued even by those who do not subscribe to Kripke-Putnam semantics, and there is a kernel of truth to it. Unfortunately, successor theories are not easily seen as referring to "the same entities" in any straightforward way because theories are, in part, holistic, and their individual terms do not refer on their own. What "phlogiston" or "ether" referred to is not so easy to describe in modern terms, but theories based on them certainly covered large classes of phenomena.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks, just saw your comment now! If you mind elaborating a bit, you're saying that theoretical terms refer qua conceptual apparatus, but that's in question; or is your point that recurring to the causal-historical theory is too ad hoc here? What is this kernel of truth?

Comment: The kernel of truth is that both are used to describe the same phenomena, up to observational improvements, but phenomena do not map to theoretical entities (and relations) in anything like 1-1 way. One can explain continuity this way for the more down to Earth terms like "gold" or "water", but not for more abstract theoretical entities. Even Kripke-Putnam themselves did not argue it far beyond the natural kinds. In a similar way, one can not explain much of language only by naming some simple objects and pointing at them.